# using ICU4C , how to compare UTF8 strings

Tags: c++, utf-8, icu

using ICU4C I would like to compare 2 utf8 strings in c++. 
Up to now, I've been using this:

ICU4C version 54.1

ICU is compile on macOSX and I used this additional compilation flag U_CHARSET_IS_UTF8=1

The ICU function I'm using:

```
    Locale loc("fr", "CA");
    UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    Collator *pColl = Collator::createInstance(loc, status);
    ASSERT_FALSE(U_FAILURE(status));
    pColl->setStrength(Collator::SECONDARY);

    UnicodeString unicodeStringLhs("étiennematineau")
    UnicodeString unicodeStringRhs("zeaval")
```

This part of the code is somewhere else in the application.
First I convert the unicode to UTF8

```
    std::string strLhs;
    strLhs = unicodeStringLhs.toUTF8String<std::string>(strLhs);

    std::string strRhs;
    strRhs = unicodeStringRhs.toUTF8String<std::string>(strRhs);

    std::cout<<strLhs<<':'<<strRhs<<"\n";

    const char * test =  strLhs.c_str(); //  "\303\251tiennematineau"
```

Then using compareUTF8 to compare.

```
    int r = pColl->compareUTF8(strLhs, strRhs,status);
```

**What is does**

In this specific case compareUTF8 return -1.

**What I was expecting**

that compareUTF8 return 1
as in python where u"étiennematineau" > u"zeaval" is true

**The question**

Am I using those function the right way?
Is this this the expected behaviour ? 
What should I do to match my expectation ?

thank you all

Comment: Why is `u"étiennematineau" > u"zeaval"`? Doesn't `'é'` comes before `'z'`?